# Proving that a sequence converges weak-star in $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $f \in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ be a periodic function with period $1$. How can one prove that the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of functions given by $$f_n(x)=f(nx)$$ converges weak-star in $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ where the limit is the constant function $\overline f$ with $$\overline f \equiv\int_0^1f(x) \, dx \, ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})=\Big( L^1(\mathbb{R}) \Big)^*$, and that for a Banach space $X$ a sequence $y_n\in X^*$ converges to $y$ weak-* if $y_n(x)\rightarrow y(x)$ for all $x\in X$. Hence what you need to show is that
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}g\cdot f_n dx \rightarrow \int_\mathbb{R}g\cdot \overline{f}dx \qquad \forall g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}).
$$

We can notice by periodicity of $f$ that $\int_{k}^{k+1} \big( f(x)-\overline{f}  \big)dx=0$.

Let $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap C_c(\mathbb{R})$. Hence:
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}g(x) f(nx) dx
= \int_{-K}^Kg(x)f(nx)dx$$
and
$$\int_\mathbb{R}g(x)\overline{f}dx
= \overline{f}\int_{-K}^Kg(x)dx
$$
for some $K\in \mathbb{N}$.

Rewriting this we get that:
\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R}g(x) \big(f(nx)-\overline{f} \big) dx
& = \frac{1}{n}\int_{-nK}^{nK} g\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\cdot \big(f(x)-\overline{f}\big)dx \\
& = \frac{1}{n} \overset{nK-1}{\underset{j=-nK}{\sum}}\int_{j}^{j+1}g\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\cdot \big(f(x)-\overline{f}\big)dx.
\end{align}

Since $g$ is continuous and compactly supported, we know that $-M \le g(x)\le M$ for some $M>0$.

Then it holds that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n} \overset{nK-1}{\underset{j=-nK}{\sum}}\int_{j}^{j+1}g\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\cdot\big(f(x)-\overline{f}\big)dx
& \le \frac{1}{n} \overset{nK-1}{\underset{j=-nK}{\sum}}\int_{j}^{j+1}M \cdot\big(f(x)-\overline{f}\big)dx \\
& = \frac{1}{n} \overset{nK-1}{\underset{j=-nK}{\sum}}M\int_{j}^{j+1}\big(f(x)-\overline{f}\big)dx
= 0.
\end{align}

Similarly $\frac{1}{n} \overset{nK-1}{\underset{j=-nK}{\sum}}\int_{j}^{j+1}g\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\cdot\big(f(x)-\overline{f}\big)dx \ge 0$, hence for $\frac{1}{n}< \delta$ we obtain that $$\int_\mathbb{R}g(x) \big(f(nx)-\overline{f} \big) dx=0.$$

Since $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^1$, this implies that for all $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ there exists a sequence $g_m\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap C(\mathbb{R})$, $g_m \overset{L^1}{\rightarrow}g$ and 
$$
0
=\int_\mathbb{R}g_m(x) \big(f(nx)-\overline{f} \big) dx
\to \int_\mathbb{R}g(x) \big(f(nx)-\overline{f} \big) dx.
$$

This argument is true for all $g\in L^1$ hence, $f_n$ converges weak-* to $f$.

**Edit:(Answer to viktor question in the comments)**

I think this could work. Given your rational edgepoints $a,b$, you can write for all $n$, 
$$ m_1(n)= \lceil{na} \rceil \quad m_2(n)=\lfloor nb \rfloor $$
where $na=m_1(n)-r_1(n)$ and $nb=m_2(n)+r_2(n)$. When $r_1(n)$ and $r_2(n)$ are zero you have your identity
$$ \frac{1}{n}\int_{na}^{nb}f(u) du=(b-a)\int_0^1f(u)du. $$
You also have

$$ \begin{align} \frac{1}{n}\int_{na}^{nb}f(u) du&= \frac{1}{n}\int_{na}^{m_1(n)}f(u)du +\frac{1}{n}\int_{m_1(n)}^{m_2(n)}f(u)du+ \frac{1}{n}\int_{m_2(n)}^{nb}f(u)du 
\end{align}$$

Because $f\in L^\infty$, we can conclude

$$ \Bigg\vert\frac{1}{n}\int_{na}^{m_1(n)}f(u)du\Bigg\vert \leq \frac{1}{n} \Vert f \Vert_\infty \cdot \left( m_1(n)-na \right) \leq \frac{1}{n} \Vert f \Vert_\infty \cdot 1 \rightarrow 0,$$
and similarly

$$ \Bigg\vert\frac{1}{n}\int_{m_2(n)}^{nb}f(u)du\Bigg\vert \leq \frac{1}{n} \Vert f \Vert_\infty \cdot \left( nb-m_2(n) \right) \leq \frac{1}{n} \Vert f \Vert_\infty \cdot 1 \rightarrow 0. $$

Notice that $na-nb=m_2(n)-m_1(n) +\Big(r_2(n)+r_1(n) \Big)$, hence 
$$ \lim \frac{1}{n}\int_{na}^{nb}f(u) du = \lim \frac{m_2(n)-m_1(n)}{n}\int_0^1 f(u)du=(b-a)\int_0^1f(u)du $$

Comment: Could this proof be simplified when using that the span of characteristic functions is dense in $L^1$? As $\mathbb Q\subset\mathbb R$ is dense, it also suffices to use $\chi_{[a,b]}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb Q$. Then \begin{align*}
        \langle f_n-\overline{f},\chi_{[a,b]}\rangle
        & = \int_{\mathbb R} (f_n(x)-\overline{f})\chi_{[a,b]}(x)dx\\
        & =\int_a^bf(nx)dx-(b-a) \overline{f}\\
        & =\frac{1}{n}\int_{na}^{nb}f(u) du -(b - a) \overline{f}\end{align*} But how do I go one from there? I want the last term to be equal to $$(b - a) \int_0^1f(u)du - (b - a) \overline{f}=0$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I only stumbled into it by chance, please notify me next time with the @ :)